# Using $f(x+a) = e^{a\frac{d}{dx}}f(x)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Using Taylor series for an infinitly differentiable function we've
$$f(x+a) = e^{a\frac{d}{dx}}f(x)$$

But if I choose $f(x)=e^x$ and $x=1,a=2$

I end up with $$e^{3}=e^{2 e}$$.

Can anyone please hint at my mistake. Thank you so much.

Comment: How can we locate your mistake when you don't show what you did? _How_ dd you end up with that?

Comment: The below answers answer it. I was confusing myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand what an "operator" is, and how it acts.
$$
f(x) = e^x
\\
\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k f(x) = \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\; f(x) = e^x
\\
e^{a\frac{d}{dx}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k}{k!}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k
$$
so that
\begin{align}
e^{a\frac{d}{dx}} f(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k}{k!}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k f(x)
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k}{k!}e^x = e^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k}{k!}
= e^x e^a = e^{x+a}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I was confusing myself.

Answer (score 1):

You've mistakenly replaced $\left[\exp\left(2\tfrac{d}{dx}\right)\right]e^x$ with $\exp\left(2\tfrac{d}{dx}e^x\right)$.

Comment: Yes that's it , TYSM.